# Dismissing UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.1

I have the following code:

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:secondView.view];
[imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

My question is: How can I dismiss the ModalViewController from "SecondViewController"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must call the following on `imagePicker` from a `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method in `secondView`.

For example:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // process message
    [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: almost; secondView.view is the overlay, not the delegate,  You would need to set the image picker's delegate to secondView as well.

Comment: *sidenote:* `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is now deprecated in iOS6

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer no longer works in iOS7. Below is the method which should be used instead.

Again, this method should be called on the `UIImagePicker` from the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```